# Populating a TableView in ViewDidAppear

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to do what I thought would be simple, but is seems quite complex.

I am trying to create a leaderboard screen.

I have the following:

```
NSArray* playerNames
NSArray* playerScores
```

My leaderboard tab is a viewcontroller. Inside, it has a tableview. The tableview has an outlet.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface LeaderboardViewController : UIViewController
{

}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *leaderboardTable;
- (SimonGameModel*) model;
@end
```

When the view did load, I get the above 2 arrays (both of same length) from my model. They correspond to the latest scores.

What I need is for each table cell to tave 2 lables so that I end up with a leaderboard that looks something like this:

```
Tim            200
John           100
Jack            50
```

etc...

I have been reading apple's docs for nearly an hour and I am confused as to how to do this.

I created a prototype with the labels I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [leaderboardTable setDataSource:self];
   [leaderboardTable setDelegate:self];
 }
```

you must create your custom cell in this way:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 return [playerNames count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {


     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"leader";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [leaderboardTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 UILabel *labelName = [[UILabel alloc] initWhitFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0,160,44);
 [labelName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
 labelName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [cell.contentView addSubView:labelName];

 UILabel *labelValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWhitFrame:CGRectMake(165, 0, 150, 44);
 [labelValue setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
 labelValue.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [cell.contentView addSubView:labelValue];

  }

 labelName.text = [playerNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 labelValue.text = [playerScores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have not set your LeaderboardViewController as your tableview's dataSource. LeaderboardViewController will have to conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941

Also, remember to register a UITableViewCell xib or class with your tableview.

You will be populating your cells with data from your arrays in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Could you give me a simple example with stub methods? Do I need another class that inherits UITableView ?

My prototype has 2 labels, how does that play into this.  I'm also unsure about the nib part.

Thanks